# How do I modify the CSS from a specific element in #shadow-root (open)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, dom

Example below. How would I change the display of the p in the SR element?  `#one ?SHADOW-ROOT-QUERY-SELECTOR? p { display: none};`

```html
<div>
  <p>My Website</p>

  <div id="one">
   <!--#shadow-root (open)-->
      <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
         <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the child selector (`#three p`) or the immediate child selector (`#three > p`). Like this for the immediate child selector:

```css
#three>p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>My Website</p>

  <div id="one">
    <!--#shadow-root (open)-->
    <div id="two">
      <div id="three">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's more on CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)